# Looking for less messy Google Sheets formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am making a spreadsheet counting how many unit each 'thing' has and the formula is getting out of hand. The number in the row needs to be multiplied with the number in row 1 and then added together to display in column A.

[image: example]

The formula I end up with in column A already looks messy here but in the actual document it's currently over 20 columns and likely to get over 40.

```
=(C2*$C$1)+(D2*$D$1)+(E2*$E$1)+(F2*$F$1)+(G2*$G$1)+(H2*$H$1)+(I2*$I$1)+(J2*$J$1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete everything from A2:A. Then place the following formula in A2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B="",,MMULT(C2:J*C1:J1,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(C1:J1),1,1,0))))`

This one formula will produce all results for all rows where Col B has data.

The first condition of the `IF` clause checks to see if the corresponding cell in Col B is blank. If it is, then null is returned for that row in Col A. If not, the `MMULT` calculation is done.

`MMULT` is matrix multiplication, and it would take too long to explain fully. For your purposes, it will multiply each element in C2:J by the corresponding number at the top of its columns (C1:J1), multiply each of those by 1 and then add those together by row. With `MMULT` the second matrix must have the same number of elements *down* as the first matrix has *across*. `SEQUENCE` makes sure of that by counting the `COLUMNS` for the number of elements for rows in the matrix, designating `1` column, a count starting at `1` and an increment for each step of `0` (in other words, a stack of `1`s with as many rows as there are columns in C1:J1).

If you really *want* a drag-down formula for some reason, delete my proposed formula above from A2 and place this in A2 instead:

`=SUMPRODUCT(C2:J2*C$1:J$1)`

Then drag it down to each cell below it as needed.

`SUMPRODUCT` does what it says: it finds the product of a multiplication for an array and then sums those results.